# How can I show in HTML a file?

Tags: css, html, tags

I have the next problem, I want to make a tutorials and I want to use Github for save all the files and the website show the code from the raw file.

The file can be an HTML, CSS, Javascript, Python and more.

For  example one of the files is on this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonylattke/python_helpers/master/10_0_importing_files.py). I think the code in HTML can be:

```
<iframe src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonylattke/python_helpers/master/10_0_importing_files.py"></iframe>
```

But it doesn't work. Thanks for your time and I appreciate your help

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Do you want to display part of a webpage within another webpage? Or do you want to do something different?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364025/embeding-file-from-github-repository-into-webpage

Comment: You are right HJ05 what I want to do is exactly what yo show on that question. With that you can show code and any file on your HTML. By the way the others answer are useful tips too for show files

Answer (score 2):

```html
<object data="MPSC syllabus.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
</object>
```

I think it will solve your problem. Please dont forget to tick the answer right if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I gues u can try changing the file extension to a none web file like instead of *.html u can write it as *.htmll or something like that or even add a custom html like *.txt to look like this *.html.txt